# Get disparity map from two images taking by single moving camera

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am taking two images using single moving camera. I tried to take them from same epipolar line.

[image]

[image]

Then I compute disparity in Matlab.

```
I1 = imread('4.jpg');  %right image
I2 = imread('3.jpg');  %left image

figure
imshow(stereoAnaglyph(I1,I2));
title('Red-cyan composite view of the stereo images');

disparityRange = [-6 26];
disparityMap = disparity(rgb2gray(I1),rgb2gray(I2),'DisparityRange',disparityRange);

figure 
imshow(disparityMap,disparityRange);
title('Disparity Map');
colormap(gca,jet) 
colorbar
```

My output consists of many noise. When I try to compute with tsukuba left and right images, it shows a perfect and smooth disparity map. Why does it happen? Do I miss any important step? Does the disparity range affect?

[image]

Comment: Side note: The `jet` colormap is one of the worst choices you can use for this type of data. You want some diverging colormap here

Comment: Also, "trying" to take them in the epipolar plane and them being in the epipolar plane are very different concepts ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I am totally new to stereo vision and I do not really understand. Why jet colormap is the worst choice? Is it just worst in visualization? So I have to rectify the images to make them in same epipolar plane?

Comment: Yes, jet is various colors, while in here you have diverging data. Either choose a diverging colormap, or a uniform colormap (such as parula, gray)

Comment: I have been looking around, and your results don't seem too crazy, depends on what algorithm MATLAB uses. The sample dataset is very nice, but for any arbitrary image, its very hard to compute disparity maps, especially when you have uniform areas. The wall looks almost the same everywhere, so the disparity map "randomly" matches it. Notice how everything that is indeed an object gets properly plotted, but all uniform areas are not

Answer (score 2):

It would helped if you could post the implemented `disparity` function.
I suggest to pass a positive number of disparity value `e.g. 59`
You may try the following:

```
function disparity_map = disparity(I1, I2, disp_value)

shiftedWin = 5 %any odd number
windowSize = (shiftedWin-1)/2;

lImage = im2double(I1)
rImage = im2double(I2)
disp2 = uint8(imread(I1));

[lRow , lCol] = size(lImage);
DispImg = zeros(lRow,lCol);

for i = windowSize+1 :1: lRow-windowSize
    for j = windowSize+1 :1:  lCol-windowSize-disp_value

        previousScore = 9999;
        bestDisparity = 0;

        lReg = lImage(i-windowSize:i+windowSize,j-windowSize:j+windowSize);

        for cDisparity = 1:disp_value

                rReg = rImage(i-windowSize:i+windowSize,j+cDisparity-windowSize:j+windowSize+cDisparity); %% correlated shifted window

                %%SAD method%%
                tempScore = abs(rReg - lReg);
                curScore = sum(tempScore(:));        
                %lineSums = [lineSums, corrScore];

            if (previousScore > curScore)                
                previousScore = curScore;
                bestDisparity = cDisparity;
            end
        end

        DispImg(i,j) = bestDisparity;

    end
end

ilumImg = DispImg *4;
imagesc(ilumImg)
colorbar

diffImg = imabsdiff(uint8(ilumImg),disp2);
figure
imshow(diffImg,[])
```